# Run a function / process as background in C# asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to this but I have a question: what is the best way, to run a function / process as background in C# ASP.NET MVC ?

For context, I'm creating a website for a project that does monitoring through snmp. The thing is that the various alerts have different timeouts between them. I want to go through all of alerts and see if the time between the last check and now is already passed. If so, the program will do another monitoring for that alert. It is supposed to run as background so it doesn't affect the rest of the site.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: Use the OS to run a program (your process) on a schedule. This would be completely separate and completely out of process of the website.

Answer (score 0):

Check this great article here: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

TLDR: you have built in and third party options.

- The built in is not as polished and with as many offerings as for example hangfire
- The built in tries to delay the app pool recycle to finish the job.
- Hangfire has good connectivity with redis and other persistence options

Both are not suitable for long running jobs, especially longer than the application pool restart period.

Both need some recovery mechanism in case the task is interrupted abruptly.

You can build an application running on a scheduler or a windows service or a linux cron job or even try something on the cloud as web jobs. Those are not related to the iis lifecycles and have none of the drawbacks mentioned above.